# Schottky diode EAS test circuit

Tags: diodes, test, schottky, avalanche-breakdown

I'd like to test the non-repetitive avalanche energy (EAS) of a particular Schottky diode (VS-12CWQ10FN-M3), but I've never done this test before and can't find a typical test circuit. This comes from the absolute maximum ratings in the datasheet:

[image]

Here's something that I cooked up. Will this do the trick or should I be looking for a different method?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feYnZE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The other question I have pertains to the nature of the damage caused by EAS. A 12 mJ transient doesn't seem like it should have nearly enough heat energy to damage the hefty diode by thermal means. How does going above the EAS value actually cause degradation or damage to the diode? Is it something similar to secondary breakdown in BJTs where heat gets concentrated in a very small area?

Comment: I would connect the Schottky in parallel with the MOSFET body diode, cathode to drain and anode to ground. The way you put it will actually bias the diode when the transistor turns on. You want the voltage at the drain to increase quickly at turn off until the Schottky avalanches. Of course, the MOSFET \$BV_{DSS}\$ must be way higher than the Schottky breakdown voltage so that the diode avalanches first. Start with a low duty ratio at low frequency first.

Comment: Great thanks, do you have any insight on how EAS damages the silicon? The reason I ask is that I've got a couple shorted diodes that came back from the field without any burn marks or other visible signs of damage. I'm hoping I can replicate the failure with this test.

Comment: The problem is that the \$E_{AS}\$ parameter given in the data-sheet is far from a practical case in which you have a small inductance and a high current (\$I_{rms}^2\$) which fuses the junction. Are these diodes used in a switching converter or in a static application? What safety margin do you have, worst-case reverse voltage versus max rating? Destruction can occur because of a violated max rating, assembly defect, package delamination etc. Hard to tell when failure analysis shows a completely fused junction actually. Most conclusions are EOS (electrical overstress).

Comment: The diode is conducting in parallel instead of in series to test the EAS

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: What? You need me to draw a series conducting diode?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 You said the diode should be conducting in parallel instead of in series to test the EAS. In parallel with what? I've already got it in parallel with the inductor.

Comment: @pr871 pls read what I wrote again